# How do I show what values of $N$ that $10N\log N > 2N^2?$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, logarithms

My goal is to find the values of $N$ such that $10N \log N > 2N^2$

I know for a fact this question requires discrete math.

I think the problem revolves around manipulating the logarithm. The thing is, I forgot how to manipulate the logarithm using discrete math.

My question is how do I manipulate this equation in a way such that I can find the values of N such that the equation is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First divide by $2N$ on both sides,

$5\log N> N$ (since $N>0$ then the inequality stays the same)

Then by raising to the $e$ power on both sides (the exponential is an increasing function) you'll get

$e^{5\log N}>e^{N}\implies e^{\log N^5}>e^N \implies N^5>e^{N}$

Can you end it from here?

Comment: Last step is incorrect!  Should be $N^5 \gt e^N$.

Comment: Which makes 1000% sense, so the values of N such that N$^5$ > e$^N$ implies the condition above is also true since they are equivalent.

Comment: Yes sorry this was a typo...

Answer (score 2):

In the real domain, consider the function
$$f(x)=5\log(x)-x$$ The first derivative cancels at $x=5$ and by the second derivative test, this is a maximum. So, there is a limited range of $x$ where $f(x) >0$.

Sooner or later, you will learn that the zero's of $f(x)$ are given in terms of Lmabert function, that is to say that $f(x) >0$ if
$$-5 W\left(-\frac{1}{5}\right) < x < -5 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{5}\right)$$ which, numerically are $1.30$ and $12.71$.

So, for your problem with integer numbers $2 \leq n \leq 12$.

Comment: Question,can you elaborate a few things on the Lambert function here ? For example, how to find the omega constant in this context. ( I looked up a Youtube video.) However, I'm a bit confused with the info I have in front of me right now.

Comment: Also, how did you come to the conclusion that for -5W(x) | x is -1/5 , why do you have a (negative) in front of 5W and how did you come to that?

Comment: Furthermore, why is there a floor (negative) 1 times -1/5 on the right side of the equation?

Answer (score 0):

$N \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

$10N\log(N)> 2N^2$

If and only if

$5 \log(N)> N$

If and only if

$e^{5\log(N)} > e^{N}$

If and only if

$N^5 > e^{N}$